# How to set arithabort on at the instance level for all new dbs?

Tags: sql-server

How do I set Arithabort 'on' for al new databases created in SQL Server? I know how to set it at the db level but how do I set it at the instance level?

Comment: Ok, I'll bite... `ARITHABORT` is a session-scoped option, something that's set to `ON` or `OFF` by clients as and when needed - sometimes on a [per-statement basis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-arithabort-transact-sql#examples). How are you setting it `ON` at the database level?

Comment: I right click on a Database in SSMS, right-click, select properties then options and in the miscellaneous box select arithmetic abort enabled - set to true/false/.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - you can do that here [`ALTER DATABASE SET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=sql-server-ver16) - but as most or every client will set it automatically I doubt the value set there is used much/at all in practice.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? ARITHABORT is effectively on with most clients due to `ANSI_WARNINGS ON` and database compatibility greater than 80 (SQL 2000). The database setting is a no-op.

Comment: I support thousands of databases and some times I find it set off. I run sp_msforeachdb to set it on for all dbs but I don't want to keep doing this.

Comment: Why are you bothering to set it on? What benefit do you thing setting it `ON` gives you?

Comment: Scripts run faster with it on and its part of MS recommendations to keep it on.

Comment: Scripts won't run faster with it on. The database setting is almost entirely (if not entirely) ignored as clients will set it explicitly anyway.  Plus for  `ARITHABORT` this is further ignored anyway as Dan explains. If you think scripts run faster because you changed this once and you saw an improvement then this was likely a parameter sniffing issue https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html - and to be clear if the problem plan had been cached with `ARITHABORT ON` then you would have seen similar improvements by setting it `OFF`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your comment:

> I support thousands of databases and some times I find it set off. I
> run sp_msforeachdb to set it on for all dbs but I don't want to keep
> doing this

TL;DR, it is likely you do not need to change the `ARITHABORT` database default setting at all.

`ARITHABORT ON` is implicitly set when clients connect with `ANSI_WARNINGS ON` (as do modern drivers) and the database compatibility level is 90 (SQL 2005) or higher. The default database `ARITHABORT ON` setting need only be set if you are using an unsupported SQL Server version (which allows database compatibility level 80 or lower) or use a client driver that doesn't set `ANSI_WARNINGS ON` when connecting, such as the long obsolete DB-Library driver.

Be aware that an implictly set `ARITHABORT ON` setting is not exposed by DMVs, the bit 64 @@OPTIONS flag, or DBCC USEROPTIONS. These report `ARITHABORT OFF` even when implicitly set due to `ANSI_WARNINGS ON` and database compatibility 90+. `ARITHABORT ON` will be reported only after a T-SQL `SET ARITHABORT ON;` is executed by the client.

Also, regarding  your other comment:

> Scripts run faster with it on and its part of MS recommendations to keep it on.

The MS documentation states "Setting ARITHABORT to OFF can negatively impact query optimization, leading to performance issues." This is likely why MS went through the effort of turning it on by default as described above. Consider the only way to turn it off (with modern client drivers and 90+ compatibility) is with an explicit `SET ARITHABORT OFF;` T-SQL statement in app code or non-default ODBC setting. Furthermore, the effect of `ARITHABORT` on performance is often misconstrued as the answers to [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9840/why-would-set-arithabort-on-dramatically-speed-up-a-query) discuss since the *explicit* `ARITHABORT` session setting is part of the query plan cache key.

Answer (score 0):

Each new database that is created in a SQL Server instance is based on the **model** database of that instance. The **model**'s database setting for **Arithmetic Abort Enabled** is set to **False**. This is why each new database is configured with the setting turned off (**False**).

## Answering Your question

> How do I set Arithabort 'on' for al new databases created in SQL Server?

#### Using SQL Server Management Studio

1. Right-click the **model** database
2. Open **Properties**
3. Switch to **Options**
4. Scroll down until you find **Arithmetic Abort Enabled**
5. Change the value from False to **True**
6. Click on **OK** to close the properties window.
7. Create a new database....

#### Using SQL Statement

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [model] SET ARITHABORT ON WITH NO_WAIT;
GO
```

....then create a new database.